# Are normal metric currents dense in the space of all metric currents?

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, metric-spaces

It is classical that Euclidean normal currents are dense in the space of all currents.
This can be achieved through mollification.

What I want to know if this is still true for metric currents.
In particular I am interested if the space of Normal 1-currents is always dense in the space of all 1-currents for any separable metric space.

Even more specifically I want to know if it is possible for a metric space to have metric currents while having no normal metric currents.

It would make sense that a positive density result could be achieved for nicely supported measures in Banach spaces, but I cannot be sure how to proceed for badly behaved metric spaces since mollifications would lead outside of the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, and it is pretty trivial apparently.
Let us look at $[0,1]\subseteq\mathbb R$ and define on it the simplest current
$$
T(fd\pi)=\int_0^1f(t)\pi'(t)dt.
$$

Now we enumerate the rational numbers on it $\{q_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[0,1]$ and given any positive $1>\varepsilon>0$ and any positive element $r\in\ell^1$ such that
$$
\|r\|_1\leq\varepsilon/2
$$
so we can define the compact set
$$
K=[0,1]\setminus\bigcup_n B(q_n,r_n).
$$
Since we have that $K$ is completely disconnected and $\mathcal L^1(K)>1-\varepsilon$ we have that
$$
T_{|K}(fd\pi)=\int_K f(t)\pi'(t)dt
$$
is a current but it is not normal anymore.
We can conclude that $K$ as a metric space has non trivial currents but cannot have normal currents since if it had any they would be supported on curves, and since $K$ is completely disconnected, that cannot happen.